# Is it possible (or is there any tool) to control mouse scroll speed with modifier keys in Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, scrolling

There is a setting to set how many lines to scroll when you use your mouse wheel. That's OK and I know how to change it. But in some apps I need a finer control, say I want to scroll one line with each step. I just wonder if there's a way to control that, e.g. hold `alt` key to scroll one line (instead of the 3 lines set in control panel).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the machine and driver. My ThinkPad allows 1 line and higher than 6, so speed is offered. My TrackPoint also has a speed control.

On this machine, the driver is from Elan.  Former ThinkPads used Synaptics drivers.

The driver must  be compatible with your machine so see if an updated driver for your machine is available.

If such a driver is not available, then you may be out of luck.

Synaptics Drivers are customized for each machine they provide a driver for. This is also true (as far as I know) for other driver manufacturers.

[Synaptics driver](https://www.synaptics.com/products/touchpad-family)

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party applications such as free [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/) that allow changing behavior of the scroll wheel. *X-Mouse Button Control* has different "layers" (profiles) that can be activated by keyboard or a mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool would be [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or from the [Windows store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/autohotkey-store-edition/9NQ8Q8J78637).

To use the Alt key to change scroll speed try this script:

```
Speed1 = 3
Speed2 = 1
~!::
Send {WheelUp %Speed2%}
Send {WheelDown %Speed2%}
Keywait,!
Send {WheelUp %Speed1%}
Send {WheelDown %Speed1%}
Return
```